# Can be the kernel infinite dimensional?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T:H\to H$ be a continuous, compact, self adjoint linear operator on the Hilbert space H. Can we have $\dim \ker(T)=\infty$?

Comment: Did you intend to ask: "Can we have $dim (ker(T))<\infty$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The zero map (given by $T(x)=0$) is a compact, continuous, self-adjoint linear operator with $\dim\ker$ equal to the dimension of $H$. So, if $H$ is infinite-dimensional...

For a non-trivial example, take, for instance, orthogonal projection onto a line: $T(x_1, x_2,\ldots) = (x_1, 0,0,0,\ldots)$.

Comment: Can you also give a non-trivial example?

Comment: @uniquesolution sure